# ¿Como insertar elementos de un array en base de datos Mysql con PHP?

Tags: php

Amigos alguno que me pueda ayudar con este código, resulta que a la hora de insertar un elemento solo se insertan los últimos del arreglo, los demás no los toma en cuenta.
Llegué a realizar un var_dump() para confirmar que están todos los elementos y efectivamente así es
Aca el código:

```
if(!empty($_SESSION["CARRITO"])){
                                        $count = count($_SESSION["CARRITO"]);
                                        foreach($_SESSION["CARRITO"] as $keys => $values){
                                            $sql = "INSERT INTO DETALLE(ID_FACTURA,IDENTIFICACION,CODIGO_PRODUCTO,NOMBRE_PRODUCTO,DESCRIPCION,CANTIDAD_DETALLE,PRECIO_DETALLE,TOTAL_DETALLE)
                                            VALUES('".$txt_factura."','".$txt_num_ide."','".$values["codigo_producto"]."','".$values["nombre_producto"]."','".$values["descripcion_producto"]."','".$values["cantidad"]."','".$values["precio_producto"]."','".$total."')";
                                            $execute = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); 
                                        }
                                       }else{
                                        echo    "<script>
                                        alert('Se debe añadir elementos al carrito');
                                         </script>";
                                       }
```

Comment: La variable SESSION "CARRITO" contiene lo qué buscas cierto?

Comment: Deberias de guardar tu arreglo en y no $_SESSION, y recorrer el nuevo arreglo

Comment: Guardarlo en que perdon?

Answer (score 0):

Cambia la linea de ejecucion de SQL por este codigo para revisar que iteraciones estan dando error y porque:

```
$execute = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or echo("Error [$sql]: ".mysqli_error($conn) . "\n", E_USER_ERROR);
```